# How to upgrade the version of Kubernetes embeded in Docker Desktop for MacOS?

Tags: kubernetes

The version of kubernetes embeded in the Docker Desktop for MacOS is outdated? Is there any way to upgrade it?

Thanks.

Comment: I've heard nothing on https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3663 in the past 3 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @David Maze for his efforts, so far we can track on the [#3663](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/366) issue for any relevant updates.